# Why IF..NOT IN(subquery) THEN not working with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, workbench

Everytime I call this procedure it doesn't do nothing, apparently there's something wrong with my if statement but I just can't figure out what, or why it's doing that, I'm used to MS Server, but I'm doing something with mysql now, please help me, and I will be really grateful :)

```
If Id_Session not in(Select Id_Session From Reps ) then

Insert Into reps (  Id_Session,
                    Id_Rep ,
                    Rep_name,
                    Rep_Start_Time,
                    Rep_End_Time,
                    Rep_Country,
                    VisitorGroupA,
                    VisitorGroupB,
                    Interactive,
                    Qualified,
                    Skill)

Values (            Id_Session,
                    Id_Rep ,
                    Rep_name,
                    Rep_Start_Time,
                    Rep_End_Time,
                    Rep_Country,
                    VisitorGroupA,
                    VisitorGroupB,
                    Interactive,
                    Qualified,
                    Skill);

End If;
```

Comment: When I execute the procedure it doesn't do nothing, meaning it doesn't insert the data, and i'm pretty sure the value is not in the subquery list.

Comment: what is `Id_Session`? a variable? or a string?

Comment: It's a parameter, that I send to the stored procedure, I just wanna check if it's in there

Comment: from which table are you inserting the values into Reps??

Comment: It's not a table, I insert the parameters that I receive in my stored procedure. it works just fine without the if statement

Comment: I am not sure, because didn't see any code, but I think you should be using `@` in front of your variables, to prevent having reinitialized each time the procedure is called

Comment: I want them to reinitialize everytime the procedure is called, because they will always be different, I mean I don't care about losing the value in my variables, since they will insert the data on the table.

Comment: but you don't want `Id_Session` to be reinitialized, can you post full code pls?

Comment: Yes I want it to be reinitialized, but don't worry CodeBird! Found an answer to my question, all I had to do was change the Id_Session parameter name to pId_Session, apparently mysql does not support this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

! Found an answer to my question, all I had to do was change the Id_Session parameter name to pId_Session, apparently mysql does not support this, thanks!